# How to make the text overlap while the image is floating to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a text overlapping the image feature on my website. This is the output I want:
[image]

So far I have got the first overlapping box done. However, I can not get the image to float to the right and text to float to the left.

```css
#image-overlap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0%;
}

.overlap-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 43%;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #000;
}

.overlap-text h1 {
  color: #000;
}

#image-overlap-right img {
  float: right;
}

.overlap-text-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 55%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 43%;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #000;
}

.overlap-text-right h1 {
  color: #000;
}

.overlap-text-right img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div id="image-overlap" class="mt-50">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x400" alt="" style="max-height: 600px;">
    <div class="overlap-text">
      <h1> Honest and open bonus structure</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="image-overlap-right" class="mt-50">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x400" alt="" style="max-height: 600px;">
    <div class="overlap-text-right">
      <h1> Marketing leading infrastructure</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/MXRZdE

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: relative` for you text blocks instead of `position: absolute`, because absolute positioning removes block from the flow, when the relative positioning leaves block in normal flow, but moves it relatively to it's initial coordinates. Just set the `position: relative` and change coordinates (`left`, `right`, `bottom` or `top`) to the result that will satisfy you :)

Answer (score 0):

WHat about this:

```css
#image-overlap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px 0%;
  index:1
}

.overlap-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 55%;
    bottom: -90%;
    width: 43%;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 200;
  z-index:9;
    color: #000;
    h1{
        color: #000;
    }
}

#image-overlap-right{
  img{
    float:right;
    position:relative;
  }
}

.overlap-text-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
    width: 43%;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #000;
    h1{
        color: #000;
    }
  img{
    float:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div id="image-overlap" class="mt-50">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x400" alt="" style="max-height: 600px;">
    <div class="overlap-text">
      <h1> Honest and open bonus structure</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="image-overlap-right" class="mt-50">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x400" alt="" style="max-height: 600px;">
    <div class="overlap-text-right">
      <h1> Marketing leading infrastructure</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used a combination of z-index and right/bottom. Anyway you have to manage the responsive part. So edit the right/bottom %s

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a simple property in order to see your second image floating right. You need to give a `width` to your `image-overlap-right` `div`.

This is your snippet width the addition of `width: 100%;`:

```css
#image-overlap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px 0%;
}

.overlap-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 55%;
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 43%;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #000;

    h1 {
        color: #000;
    }
}

#image-overlap-right{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#image-overlap-right img{
    float:right;
}

.overlap-text-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 55%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 43%;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #000;

    h1 {
        color: #000;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div id="image-overlap" class="mt-50">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x400" alt="" style="max-height: 600px;">
    <div class="overlap-text">
      <h1> Honest and open bonus structure</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="image-overlap-right" class="mt-50">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x400" alt="" style="max-height: 600px;">
    <div class="overlap-text-right">
      <h1> Marketing leading infrastructure</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also changed a little bit the position of your second text element.